# How to prevent hangfire from logging certain jobs as succeeded

Tags: .net-core, hangfire

One of my hangfire jobs is triggered every minute and it floods the succeded jobs list, so that my other jobs, that are running less frequently, are very hard to find. Is it possible to prevent hangfire from logging certain (succeeded) jobs so they do not end up showing on the list?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I ended up using this handy extension: https://github.com/face-it/Hangfire.Tags

It enables job tagging so they end up showing in a seperate tab grouped to your liking.