# Hangfire - prevent logging unnecessary "Succeeded" jobs (without tags)

Tags: hangfire, hangfire-console

Now that 2yrs has gone by since this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69650821/how-to-prevent-hangfire-from-logging-certain-jobs-as-succeeded) was asked, is there a way to prevent Hangfire from logging "spammy" Succeeded jobs in the Dashboard - aside from using the HF Tags extension noted in the related SO?

Reason - if you have a job that runs every 1min and actually only ***infrequently*** performs work , it ends up spamming the Succeeded jobs page, making it difficult to find what you're looking for.

I'm dreaming of something like:

```
public void myFunction(PerformContext context)
{
     bool wasWorkDone = false;
     //do work, set wasWorkDone
     if (!wasWorkDone)
         context.DoNotLogAsSucceededEntry(); //or maybe context.LogAsDeletedInsteadOfSucceeded();
}
```

thanks!